# babel-plugin-root-import wrong path using react-native 0.43.3

Tags: react-native, babel-plugin

I'm calling it like so: `import { SplashContainer, FooterTabsContainer, SettingsContainer } from '~/containers'`
 it should be reading from directory `/Users/jasan/Desktop/ReactModoro/app/containers`
It seems to add `app/containers/Navigator` in the path

my babel rc file:

`{  "presets": [
    "react-native-stage-0"
    ],
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-root-import", {
    "rootPathSuffix": "app"
    }]
  ]}`

[image: screenshot_2017_04_16_20_18_22]

Answer (score 3):

react-native start --reset-cache solved it. no more error